# Using templates of the wizard control

Tags: asp.net

I learnt that Template allows us to customize the look of the control. 
I am practicing wizard control and trying to use template to control it's look.
And it has following Templates available for customization:

- HeaderTemplate
- SideBarTemplate
- StartNavigationTemplate
- StepNavigationTemplate
- FinishNavigationTemplate
- LayoutTemplate

But I don't know how to use it. Can somebody share an example to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this MSDN Magazine article: [Cutting Edge: The ASP.NET 2.0 Wizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx) by Dino Esposito.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Example of `SideBarTemplate`:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="2" 
OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" 
OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">


            <!-- SidebarTemplate -->
            <SideBarTemplate>

                <!-- control that put on top of the Step List  -->
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="IMG/topimage.jpg" ImageAlign="Top" runat="server" 
                    Width="10" Height="10"/>

                <!--Step List will auto generated here-->
                <asp:DataList ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="SideBarButton" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                </asp:DataList>


                <!-- control that put below the Step List -->
                <asp:Label ID="ButtomLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </SideBarTemplate>

            <WizardSteps>

              <!-- .....WizradSteps here.....  -->

            </WizardSteps>
```